# Capturing data from a Change Password form

Tags: csrf, burp-suite, zap

Through ZAP, I was able to capture the following from a Change Password form:

```
GET /rest/user/change-password?current=P@ssword&new=password123
&repeat=password123 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0)
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
....
```

The fact that ZAP proxy (even Burp suite) was able to capture details related to password changes is somewhat considered to be a sign of "poor CSRF defense" by this author:

> "If the CSRF defense was strong enough in Juice Shop, Burp Suite could
> not have captured that easily. Here the output is the clear indication
> of weakness. Any strong application would not have allowed capturing
> that data."

[source](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bug-Bounty-Hunting-Security-Vulnerabilities/dp/1484253906) and [Google Books Excerpt](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=H-69DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%22If%20the%20CSRF%20defense%20was%20strong%20enough%20in%20Juice%20Shop%22&source=bl&ots=j3MDJil1M-&sig=ACfU3U1XkJ6nAnPrQQZ-_bvlnU6mO6pB5A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj31rmqxrryAhWDYcAKHY50ABUQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22If%20the%20CSRF%20defense%20was%20strong%20enough%20in%20Juice%20Shop%22&f=false)

Can anyone explain to me the reason for that?

A strong web application should not allow capturing such details (at least this is what the author says). But why?

Comment: considered to be a sign of "poor CSRF defense" you're saying it is not? I' m referring to this book Bug Bounty Hunting for Web Security (Sanjib Sinha) it states exactly that"If the CSRF defense was strong enough in Juice Shop, Burp Suite could not have
captured that easily. Here the output is the clear indication of weakness.
Any strong application would not have allowed capturing that data." In a nutshell my question was: how can he say that is someone able to tell me why?

Comment: If that's really a quote from the book you should request a refund.

Comment: "Not allowed capturing that data" How on earth is a web application supposed to stop someone from listening? If that's an actual quote you're reading a book that doesn't understand a thing about security or how TLS works. Nor about cRSF.

Comment: I just read the section in Google Books. I think there was a section edited out by mistake. The author contradicts himself and states different facts without explaining that he changed anything. There are some very basic continuity errors in that section.

Comment: I think the author is simply talking about the `GET` and he is referring to the fact that CSRF defenses include not using GET for state-change operations (like password setting). He is overstating things because it's the CSRF section of the Juice Shop challenges. It's all just poorly edited and written. I'm not surprised that you are confused.

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous issues with your example.

1. It uses the GET verb and no apparent session cookie or account identification:

- So how is the account to be updated being determined?
- The URL (and thus passwords) will be cached in browser history (horrible for shared systems in libraries, schools, etc.).

  - [OWASP reference](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url)

2. It's seemingly subject to CSRF (since there's no obvious cookie or param value associated to prevent CSRF).
3. It doesn't seem to enforce use of strong password/phrases.

Lastly it seems that you need to read up on proxies and the implications of installing CA Certs (such as those from ZAP or Burp).
The point of such a tool is to be able to analyze the traffic for issues, if ZAP or Burp couldn't "see" the information how would they make any determination of issues?

Edit: To make my answer less "RTFM'ish", as a distilled explanation: The reason that you install the ZAP or Burp CA (Certificate Authority) certificate is so that the proxy is essentially authoritative or trusted for one side of the TLS/SSL negotiation and can therefore decrypt the traffic passing through it. (Note for ZAP: If you launch a browser from within ZAP this is transparent and done for you.)

Comment: I've just provided another piece of information about my question...but you're actually saying that it's just a matter of traffic decryption...as well as absence of cookies which might prevent CSRF

Comment: Yes, it's just a matter of traffic decryption. Cookies have nothing to do with it.

Comment: That you used a proxy to do what it's meant to do doesn't prove anything about CSRF or the security of the app. If you used a proxy without trusting its CA cert or if you used straight packet capture you might have something. Hence HTTP vs. HTTPS.

Comment: To complement your point 1: https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url

Comment: The Google Books excerpt does indeed show a cookie and a token. I added the link to the OP

Comment: Proof that anything is publishable these days :( It's like the book didn't have an editor let alone a technical editor. The chapter titles are barely even English (at least the few I read via Google books excerpt).